# How to config "ubuntu/trusty64" Vagrant box properly on Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I know this question has been asked several times. But all answers on those questions haven't worked for me.

I'm trying to install a new virtual machine using VirtualBox 5.1.4 (VirtualBox-5.1.14-112924-Win) and Vagrant 1.9.1 on my Windows 10.

The error is the following:

```
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot
```

In order to avoid it I add a new line in `vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.boot_timeout = 900
```

But error persists.

I also enabled the GUI removing the comment (according to [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24229148/117259)):

```
vb.gui = true
```

However it returns a new error:

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot…
```

I also followed this answer:

> select Ubuntu server, click on Settings, go to Network tab and make
>   sure that your Cable Connected option is selected

…and cable connected option was selected. However it shows this notifications:

> invalid configuration detected

This is my Vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 900

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end

end
```

Is there another method to solve this problem?

Comment: @techraf I did it a few times. Now I did it in a new directory but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I can see: you need to enable virtualization technology (`VT-X`) extensions in BIOS in order to run virtual machines.

Your `Vagrantfile` is fine to configure a new box. However, the problem about:

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot...

...sounds like `VT-X` is disabled in your windows configuration (Basic Input/ Output System).

Try to enable this feature and box installation should works now.